# Is it possible to use a pre defined editor within a bespoke editor function

Tags: javascript, tabulator

In tabulator I would like to define a bespoke editor function which will return a predefined one according to the value of cell in the row.

Basically I would like to do something like the below within my editor definition

```js
if (cell.getValues() == true){ 
    return "tickCross"
}else{
    return "";
}
```

I have found a similar thing here but it does not seem to work with the current version of the module
https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/926

Is `Tabulator.getExtension()` still available or replaced by something else ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to combine editors in that way, each column can only have one editor set on it.

If you wanted to display a different editor based on the cell contents then you would need to create your own custom editor that performed both functions.

The Tabulator documentation has a full guide on how to [Create A Custom Editor](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/edit#edit-custom)